# Android WiFi direct requestPeers not finding any peers nearby

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Background:
Device used: Samsung Galaxy Note 10+, Samsung Galaxy S8

1. I'm developing an Android application that uses WiFi-direct to transfer photos.
2. In order to do so, I first establish BLE connection between two devices, so that they can exchange macAddress data through BLE characteristics.
3. Upon Bluetooth service is discovered in "OnServiceDiscovered" callback method, I call "discoverPeers" method.
4. When "discoverPeers()" succeeds, WifiP2PManager calls "requestPeers(channel, PeerListListener)"
5. Strangely, despite many wifi devices being present, the wifi device list is ***empty, always.***

Here is the code

```
public void discoverWifiPeers() {
        manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.e("INFO", "Discover Peers succeeded");
                manager.requestPeers(channel, myPeerListListener);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Log.e("Error", "Discover Peers failed");
            }
        });
    }

private WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener myPeerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList wifiP2pDeviceList) {
            for (WifiP2pDevice device : wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList())
            {
                if(!wifiDeviceList.contains(device))
                    wifiDeviceList.add(device);
            }
            Log.i(CommonConstants.INFO, "onPeersAvailable() - devicelist =>" + wifiDeviceList.size());
        }
    };
```

Measures I had taken:

- I searched lots of blogs and StackOverflow questions for this, and so far all of them pointed ***coarse location permission***. I added the code below.

```
private void requestCoarseLocation(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        CommonConstants.REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- It gave Wifi device list for the very first time I added the COARSE_PERMISSION, but after that one time it resumed showing empty list for the WiFi list.

How can I ***always guarantee*** to have the wifi device list of devices in proximity?